# How to make a continuous animation with citoscape.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

How to make a continuous animation with citoscape.js to simulate a small random motion on all nodes. Something that look as if they had a small gravity. I try to make nodes move around a starting point only slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

(1) Use [`ele.animate()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/animation/eles.animate) on each node, specifying a slightly modified position for each node.

(2) Apply one of the physics/forcedirected [layouts](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts) with a very short duration.